# EASY PYTHON SELENIUM: How do I click by class name?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Goal: Click by class name.

HTML:

```
<span class="Icon-Svg Link-Icon-Svg next-Link-Icon-Svg Pagination-RightControl-Link-Icon-Svg Pagination-Page-Link-Icon-Svg" 

style="-webkit-mask-image: url(&quot;https://[REDACTED]/icon/ArrowRight.svg&quot;); -webkit-mask-size: contain; -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat; -webkit-mask-position: center center;"></span>
```

Attempt:

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'Icon-Svg Link-Icon-Svg next-Link-Icon-Svg Pagination-RightControl-Link-Icon-Svg Pagination-Page-Link-Icon-Svg')
```

[Screenshot of HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1aU1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Element you are trying to locate here having multiple class names. Such element can be located by XPATH or CSS_SELECTOR while `By.CLASS_NAME` supports single class name only, so instead of

```py
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'Icon-Svg Link-Icon-Svg next-Link-Icon-Svg Pagination-RightControl-Link-Icon-Svg Pagination-Page-Link-Icon-Svg')
```

you can use

```py
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.Icon-Svg.Link-Icon-Svg.next-Link-Icon-Svg.Pagination-RightControl-Link-Icon-Svg.Pagination-Page-Link-Icon-Svg')
```

Please pay attention that locator you are using looks not too much reliable, you possibly could improve it.